# Adding Physics to OBJ Model in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, physijs, objloader

I am trying to use PhysiJS with ThreeJS. I have an OBJ model that I exported from Blender. When I load it with OBJLoader, I see that it is a BufferGeometry. I also notice that it is missing a `vertices` property, which is what PhysiJS looks for.

My ThreeJS version is r101. I would appreciate any suggestions. If there is a more suitable library, I am open to that too. I am also happy to provide any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to convert your `BufferGeometry` to `Geometry`, you can simply use the [`.fromBufferGeometry()` method](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Geometry.fromBufferGeometry).

```
// Called when your obj finishes loading
onLoadComplete(obj) {
    var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
    geom.fromBufferGeometry(obj);

    // Now you'll have access to vertices
    console.log(geom.vertices);
}
```

Comment: `geom` is in the format that I like. But when I pass it into `Physijs.ConcaveMesh`, I get a script error. Is it because `THREE.Geometry` is an abstract class?

Comment: I'm not sure what parameters Physijs is expecting, but sounds like you should be passing a `Mesh`, not a geometry. Something like `var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat); Physijs.ConcaveMesh(mesh);`, maybe? Have you looked at the source code in their examples?

Comment: Source code snippet: `Physijs.ConcaveMesh = function( geometry, material, mass ) { ... }` . If `THREE.Geometry` is not abstract, I can figure out the rest.

Comment: I found out what's wrong. I accidentally mistook one of my test geometries for material. Your code works after all :) . Thank you so much!